# Get week number based on ISO8601

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way in `SQL Server` to get week number based on specific date which would reflect
according to `ISO8601` where `Monday` is the first day of week?

Comment: @Larnu can you post full answer?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the aptly named [`ISO_WEEK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#iso_week-datepart) Datepart:

> #### iso_week datepart
>
> ISO 8601 includes the ISO week-date system, a numbering system for weeks. Each week is associated with the year in which Thursday occurs. For example, week 1 of 2004 (2004W01) covered Monday, 29 December 2003 to Sunday, 4 January 2004. European countries / regions typically use this style of numbering. Non-European countries / regions typically do not use it.

```sql
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,YourDate)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: does ISO_WEEK = ISO 8601 so means also monday as first day by default?

Comment: @Arie I have literally quoted the documentation above... It *literally* tells you what ISO standard it follows.